# ASP.net core 7 InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-core

I have just started learning ASP.net core 7 and I have run into the following issue with my code.

InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'QAMS.Data.QsccQaContext' while attempting to activate 'QAMS.Controllers.DeviceAssignmentsController'.

I tried creating the Controller from my model using the Entity Framework but it appears that it hasen't setup my DI for me and I am stuck.

QsccQaContext.cs

```
public partial class QsccQaContext : DbContext
{
    public QsccQaContext()
    {
    }

    public QsccQaContext(DbContextOptions<QsccQaContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Contact> Contact { get; set; }

    public virtual DbSet<DeviceAssignments> DeviceAssignments { get; set; }
```

Program.cs

```
using QAMS.Models;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();
```

Comment: I figured it out. I had to add builder.Services.AddDbContext<QsccQaContext>(); to the program.cs